# how to avoid postgresql backup content echo to screen

Tags: postgresql

When I using this command to backup postgres database,the backup data echo to screen:

```
screen /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_dump -v -h prod-book-db -U postgres dolphin > ./dolphin-fulldb-backup-201904130913.bak
```

How to avoid it?When using this command :

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_dump -v -h prod-book-db -U postgres dolphin > ./dolphin-fulldb-backup-201904130913.bak
```

This only echo backup log,do not contains content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably a bit late but there's an 'f' flag for this:

> -f file
>
> --file=file
>
> Send output to the specified file. This parameter can be omitted for file based output formats, in which case the standard output is used. It must be given for the directory output format however, where it specifies the target directory instead of a file. In this case the directory is created by pg_dump and must not exist before.

So you can use it like this:

```
screen /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_dump -v -f dolphin-fulldb-backup-201904130913.bak -h prod-book-db -U postgres dolphin
```